# Why are xsane scans of 4 x 6 photos so dark

Tags: scanner, canon, xsane

Ubuntu 18.04.2, Canon Pixma TS6220.
Scans of ~ letter size docs/pics are OK.  After preview of 4" x 6", and after adjusting width and height of the scan area, and selecting scan, the scanner still traverses the whole platen.  I don't think it did that with my previous all-in-one (HP).

Comment: I'm not clear on how exactly this relates to Ubuntu particularly and not general computer usage... would you please [edit] to show a bit more what you've tried and why it's particularly a Ubuntu problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Me neither.  Seems I'm never clear where the boundaries are for computer related issues.  If my question could not  possibly be related to Ubuntu, I will take it elsewhere.  Thought I would start with the OS, then go out to peripherals.